# Mutability of the Enumerator struct

Tags: c#, .net, struct, ienumerable

I have a problem with the following code:

```
  public static void RestoreToolStripMenuItem(ToolStripMenuItem item, List<string>.Enumerator enumerator )
    {
        item.Text = enumerator.Current;
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        if (item.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            var itemsWithoutSeparators = item.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>();
            foreach (var child in itemsWithoutSeparators)
            {
                RestoreToolStripMenuItem(child, enumerator);
            }
        }

}
```

After RestoreToolStripMenuItem is called recursively, enumerator is reseted (Current property points to the first element of the collection). It only can be get worked by passing enumerator by ref. I am wondering, why is this a case? Enumerator is a struct. What caused this problem, mutability of the Enumerator struct?

Comment: See: [Iterate, damn you! - Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I like Jon Skeet's articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the changing state of the structure that causes that.

If you pass the structure by value, you would be using a copy of it in the method, and the one in the calling code would not change.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the variable to type IEnumerator(Of String), and passing it once as that type.  This will cause it to be boxed once, and then behave as a class.

Comment: a change on the boxed struct will not change the original struct

Comment: @codymanix: A change on a boxed struct will not change the original struct, but if the original variable is declared as IEnumerator<String>, then the struct will be boxed *once* right after it is created; passing it to a function as an IEnumerator<String> will pass a reference to the original boxed item, so any mutations performed will affect that original boxed item.  The key is to ensure the boxing happens exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the changed Enumerator struct from the method you are calling and assign it back to your original variable.